# What is the most advanced image editing FLOSS?

Tags: image-editor

Is it still GIMP? Inkscape? Are they too different to compare? Does anything come close to the two? Are they more/less advanced than Photoshop?

**note**: advanced = more features

Answer (score 16, accepted):

GIMP and Inkscape aren't comparable: GIMP is a [bitmap editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics_editor), Inkscape is a [vector graphics editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics_editor).

GIMP is the uncontested leader amongst open source bitmap editors, feature-wise. It ranks closely with Photoshop. However GIMP has poor support for the [CMYK color space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model), which is used by most “serious” color printers; I'm told this makes it unsuitable for many applications. As usual Wikipedia has a [comparison of raster graphics editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_raster_graphics_editors), which may or may not include all important criteria.

There are many different types of vector graphics. Inkscape is a leader in its field, which is two-dimensional general-purpose schemas and scalable graphics, made mainly of straight lines, simple curves and filled regions. Other programs may perform better for [CAD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-aided_design), electronics schemas, geometrical constructions, state diagrams, fonts, 3D modeling, etc.

Answer (score 2):

[Krita](http://www.calligra-suite.org/krita/) is quite feature rich as far as capabilities if you like KDE software, I'm not really sure how it compare's to GIMP, as I'm I don't enjoy image editing, but I seem to recall reading it's better at some things (CMYK Maybe? or what is color depth?) than the GIMP. From what I have seen/heard it's a powerful  that most people never seem to hear about. Here is a pre KDE 4 comparison of [Krita and the GIMP](http://www.linux.com/archive/articles/114186).